# PhP Date and Time separation, addition and calculation

Tags: php, calculation

Another date time problem.

I have a Time when something gets busy like -> "2021-02-24 12:00:00"(string)

I have the current date like this -> date('Y-m-d h:i:s') (string)

I need to calculate how many hours : minutes : seconds passed between the two. For example (gets busy at) 2021-02-14 15:00:00 current time is 2021-02-14 16:15:00 so I need to show something similar to this: 01:15:00.

But what if more than 99 hours passed, how do I make it so it looks like this -> 120:02:36.

The question I asked yesterday was not specified enough so I got some answers in here:
(I know it's my bad)

[PhP date time addition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66336625/php-date-time-addition)

but in the end I can't use it for this problem.

Comment: Between which two? Please share more details, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert the dates to timestamps, you can then use something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/3172368/1213708 to break the time down into hours/minutes/seconds.

The `sprintf()` is just a way of formatting the date with 2 digit minutes and seconds...

```
$inputDate = new DateTime("2021-02-22 12:00:00");
$nowDate = new DateTime();

$interval = abs($inputDate->getTimeStamp() - $nowDate->getTimeStamp());
$hours = floor($interval / 3600);
$minutes = floor(($interval / 60) % 60);
$seconds = $interval % 60;

echo sprintf("%d:%02d:%02d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
```

gave as output (recently)...

```
51:22:01
```

Comment: Why don't you use date_diff? The result via the time stamp does not provide the result that is expected if a time change (daylight saving time / winter time) lies within the interval.

Comment: @jspit as it gives a DateInterval which separates out the days/hours, it would be a case of multiplying the days and add them to the hours.  It's an alternative though.

Answer (score 1):

The [DateTime extension dt](https://github.com/jspit-de/dt) has a special method for this problem: diffFormat().

```
echo dt::create('2021-02-22 12:00:00')->diffFormat("Now","%G:%I:%S");
```

Output few minutes ago:

55:52:36